# What is the difference between https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js and https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js?

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-analytics

I'm optimizing my [external Google Analytics script](http://git.io/ga-ext) and now I'm wondering:

Is there a difference between `https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js` and `https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `ssl.google-analytics.com` is just a mirror for `www.google-analytics.com`. The only difference is that Google Chrome redirects `ssl.google-analytics.com` to `https://` if you connect from HTTP.

Comment: Ok, so the best thing would be to load `//google-analytics.com/ga.js`.

Comment: Oh ok, but I don't think this could ever be a problem, right?

Comment: And are you sure? It didn't redirect me when I accessed `http://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js`.

Comment: `//google-analytics.com/ga.js.` will be the best solution as long as it loads script with the same protocol you're using on your page.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried it with Safari, Chrome and Firefox and only Chrome redirects me.

Comment: Well, it only redirects in Chrome.